# WPF/Silverlight enterprise application architecture.. what do you do?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, system-design

I've been wondering what lives in the community for quite some time now;
I'm talking about big, business-oriented WPF/Silverlight enterprise applications.

Theoretically, there are different models at play:

- Data Model       (typically, linked to your db tables, Edmx/NHibarnate/.. mapped entities)
- Business Model   (classes containing actual business logic)
- Transfer Model   (classes (dto's) exposed to the outside world/client)
- View Model       (classes to which your actual views bind)

It's crystal clear that this separation has it's obvious advantages;
But does it work in real life? Is it a maintenance nightmare?

So what do you do?
In practice, do you use different class models for all of these models?
I've seen a lot of variations on this, for instance:

- Data Model = Business Model: Data Model implemented code first (as POCO's), and used as business model with business logic on it as well
- Business Model = Transfer Model = View Model: the business model is exposed as such to the client; No mapping to DTO's, .. takes place. The view binds directly to this Business Model
- Silverlight RIA Services, out of the box, with Data Model exposed: Data Model = Business Model = Transfer Model. And sometimes even Transfer Model = View Model.
- ..

I know that the "it depends" answer is in place here;
But on what does it depend then; 
Which approaches have you used, and how do you look back on it?

Thanks for sharing,

Regards,
Koen

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I've never coded anything truly enterprisey so my experience is limited but I'll kick off.

My current (WPF/WCF) project uses Data Model = Business Model = Transfer Model = View Model!
There is no DB backend, so the "data model" is effectively business objects serialised to XML.

I played with DTO's but rapidly found the housekeeping arduous in the extreme, and the ever present premature optimiser in me disliked the unnecessary copying involved. This may yet come back to bite me (for instance comms serialisation sometimes has different needs than persistence serialisation), but so far it's not been much of a problem.

Both my business objects and view objects required push notification of value changes, so it made sense to implement them using the same method (INotifyPropertyChanged). This has the nice side effect that my business objects can be directly bound to within WPF views, although using MVVM means the ViewModel can easily provide wrappers if needs be.

So far I haven't hit any major snags, and having one set of objects to maintain keeps things nice and simple. I dread to think how big this project would be if I split out all four "models".

I can certainly see the benefits of having separate objects, but to me until it actually becomes a problem it seems wasted effort and complication.

As I said though, this is all fairly small scale, designed to run on a few 10's of PCs. I'd be interested to read other responses from genuine enterprise developers.

Answer (score 0):

The seperation isnt a nightmare at all, infact since using MVVM as a design pattern I hugely support its use. I recently was part of a team where I wrote the UI component of a rather large product using MVVM which interacted with a server application that handled all the database calls etc and can honestly say it was one of the best projects I have worked on.

This project had a

- Data Model (Basic Classes without support for InotifyPropertyChanged),
- View Model (Supports INPC, All business logic for associated view),
- View (XAML only),
- Transfer Model(Methods to call database only)

I have classed the Transfer model as one thing but in reality it was built as several layers.

I also had a series of ViewModel classes that were wrappers around Model classes to either add additional functionality or to change the way the data was presented. These all supported INPC and were the ones that my UI bound to.

I found the MVVM approach very helpfull and in all honesty it kept the code simple, each view had a corresponding view model which handled the business logic for that view, then there were various underlying classes which would be considered the Model.

I think by seperating out the code like this it keeps things easier to understand, each View Model doesnt have the risk of being cluttered because it only contains things related to its view, anything we had that was common between the viewmodels was handled by inheritance to cut down on repeated code.

The benefit of this of course is that the code becomes instantly more maintainable, because the calls to the database was handled in my application by a call to a service it meant that the workings of the service method could be changed, as long as the data returned and the parameters required stay the same the UI never needs to know about this. The same goes for the UI, having the UI with no codebehind means the UI can be adjusted quite easily.

The disadvantage is that sadly some things you just have to do in code behind for whatever reason, unless you really want to stick to MVVM and figure some overcomplicated solution so in some situations it can be hard or impossible to stick to a true MVVM implementation(in our company we considered this to be no code behind).

In conclusion I think that if you make use of inheritance properly, stick to the design pattern and enforce coding standards this approach works very well, if you start to deviate however things start to get messy.

Answer (score 0):

Several layers doesn't lead to maintenance nightmare, moreover the less layers you have - the easier to maintain them. And I'll try to explain why.

**1)** Transfer Model shouldn't be the same as Data Model

For example, you have the following entity in your ADO.Net Entity Data Model:

```
Customer
{
    int Id
    Region Region
    EntitySet<Order> Orders
}
```

And you want to return it from a WCF service, so you write the code like this:

```
dc.Customers.Include("Region").Include("Orders").FirstOrDefault();
```

And there is the problem: how consumers of the service will be assured that the `Region` and `Orders` properties are not null or empty? And if the `Order` entity has a collection of `OrderDetail` entities, will they be serialized too? And sometimes you can forget to switch off lazy loading and the entire object graph will be serialized.

And some other situations:

- you need to combine two entities and return them as a single object.
- you want to return only a part of an entity, for example all information from a `File` table except the column `FileContent` of binary array type.
- you want to add or remove some columns from a table but you don't want to expose the new data to existing applications.

So I think you are convinced that auto generated entities are not suitable for web services.
That's why we should create a transfer model like this:

```
class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<OrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

And you can freely change tables in the database without affecting existing consumers of the web service, as well as you can change service models without making changes in the database.

To make the process of models transformation easier, you can use the [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) library.

**2)** It is recommended that View Model shouldn't be the same as Transfer Model

Although you can bind a transfer model object directly to a view, it will be only a "OneTime" relation: changes of a model will not be reflected in a view and vice versa. 
A view model class in most cases adds the following features to a model class:

- Notification about property changes using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface
- Notification about collection changes using the `ObservableCollection` class
- Validation of properties
- Reaction to events of the view (using commands or the combination of data binding and property setters)
- Conversion of properties, similar to `{Binding Converter...}`, but on the side of view model

And again, sometimes you will need to combine several models to display them in a single view. And it would be better not to be dependent on service objects but rather define own properties so that if the structure of the model is changed the view model will be the same.

I allways use the above described 3 layers for building applications and it works fine, so I recommend everyone to use the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

We use an approach similar to what Purplegoldfish posted with a few extra layers. Our application communicates primarily with web services so our data objects are not bound to any specific database. This means that database schema changes do not necessarily have to affect the UI.

We have a user interface layer comprising of the following sub-layers:

1. Data Models: This includes plain data objects that support change notification. These are data models used exclusively on the UI so we have the flexibility of designing these to suit the needs of the UI. Or course some of these objects are not plain as they contain logic that manipulate their state. Also, because we use a lot of data grids, each data model is responsible for providing its list of properties that can be bound to a grid.
2. Views: Our XAML definitions of the views. To accommodate for some complex requirements we had to resort to code behind in certain cases as sticking to a XAML only approach was too tedious.
3. ViewModels: This is where we define business logic for our views. These guys also have access to interfaces that are implemented by entities in our data access layer described below.
4. Module Presenter: This is typically a class that is responsible for initializing a module. Its task also includes registering the views and other entities associated with this module.

Then we have a Data Access layer which contains the following:

1. Transfer Objects: These are usually data entities exposed by the webservices. Most of these are autogenerated.
2. Data Adapters such as WCF client proxies and proxies to any other remote data source: These proxies typically implement one or more interfaces exposed to the ViewModels and are responsible for making all calls to the remote data source asynchronously, translating all responses to UI equivalent data models as required. In some cases we use AutoMapper for translation but all of this is done exclusively in this layer.
   Our layering approach is a little complex so is the application. It has to deal with different types of data sources including webservices, direct data base access and other types of data sources such as OGC webservices.